# How to add your own color scheme to notepadqq

Tags: text-editor, editor

I have lately installed notepadqq and I am really happy with it. Is there a way to add our own color scheme to it?

Answer (score 3):

You can add CSS themes into the directory:

```
/usr/share/notepadqq/editor/libs/codemirror/theme
```

All the themes are stored in there (Except the Deafult, which can be found at `/usr/share/notepadqq/editor/libs/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css`). The syntax seems relatively simple if you wanted to create your own.

If anyone knows where I can find a Notepad++ 'Default Theme' replica, I'd be forever gratefull :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure it's the same method, but for Notepad++ you can do this by using the **Settings > Style Configurator...** menu, in the top menu bar. There should be an option to create your own.  There are a bunch of default themes: In the settings menu > Preferences > Appearance > Color Scheme (drop down menu).

Comment: There is no Style configurator unlike notepad++ in notepadqq.

Comment: Ah drat, I'll delete this answer then, sorry not to be more help!

Answer (score 0):

As of 5th October 2020, the below works :

1. Set the env variable :
   `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`
2. Install qt5ct and run it. Within qt5ct(qt5 config tool), you can change the theme for qt5. Since notepadqq runs atop qt5, notepadqq themes change as well(i.e. to whatever is set in gt5ct)